# Capping cell percentage based on percentage of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, percentage

The formula below is for F39.

The combined total of F38 and F39 is 80% of F35, up to a maximum of 90% of F17.

```
  =IF(OR(F4="None",F4="Test"),0%,MIN((0.8-F38),F17*0.9/F35-F38))
```

The formula works ok when the annual consumption (F17) is less than the output (F35) or not much more but when F17 is more than F35 it all goes wrong.

Please can someone let me know if there is something I can add to the above formula so that the combined percentage of F38 and F39 doesn't go above 90%?

Thank you

For reference, F38 is calculated as `=IF(F35="","",MIN((F17*0.375/F35),90%))`

[image]

Comment: Your formula does not match what your words said.  You said cannot exceed 90% of F17, but then proceeded to divide by F35 & subtract F38.  If you take those out then the formula will match what you said.

Comment: Sorry I really didn't explain myself very well there. Using the figures on the left image, the customer generates 5147.10 kW per year. They use only 4000 per year and we can only allow savings to be quoted on up to 90% of what they use which is 3600kWh (4000*.09). The savings are made against the generation which 5147.10, so 3600/5147.10=0.6994, which means they will use up to 69.94% of their generation. From this figure I minus the solar self-consumption savings 69.94-29.14 which gives me battery self-consumption of 40.8.

Comment: I've just amended the post

Comment: Where does the 29.14% come from?

Comment: From the solar self consumption in F38

Comment: What answer are you expecting in F39 of array2?

Comment: I would expect 90% in F38, 0% in F39 and then F40 should be 10% (the formula for that cell is 100%-F38-F39) is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
F39 = min(.9,F38 + IF(OR(F4="None",F4="Test"),0%,MIN((0.8-F38),F17*0.9/F35-F38)))
```

**Caveats** - haven't tested in Excel - so may be minor contribution.

**Assumptions**

1. You are content with the part of above eqn. you've provided (i.e. `IF(OR(F4="None",F4="Test"),0%,MIN((0.8-F38),F17*0.9/F35-F38))`)
2. F37 ╩ F38 (no circular references, although, if you wanted to be 'cheeky' re: approach/design, you could also 'tolerate' circular references briefly and opt for 'iterative calculation mode' but this is a separate topic altogether so hopefully above suffices

Answer (score 1):

With JB's help I've fixed this issue using by adding `MIN(0.9-F38)*` into the following code:

```
=IF(OR($F$4="None",$F$4="Overnight Charging"),0,MIN(0.9-F38)*MIN((0.8-F38),0.9,$F$17*0.9/F35-F38))
```

Thank you for your input, JB.